# Sign into iCloud on Mac but prevent it from receiving Apple ID two factor codes

Tags: macos, apple-id, two-factor-authentication

I am using two factor authentication on my Apple ID (not the older two step verification)

I would like to sign into a Mac with my iCloud/iTunes account and use it normally, but I would like to prevent this Mac from receiving Apple ID two factor codes and being able to authenticate new devices. If possible I would also like to have Find My Mac enabled.

Apple’s documentation leads me to believe this is possible:

> The device list shows the devices that you're currently signed in to with your Apple ID. Select a device to view the model, serial number, and other useful information, including whether or not the device is trusted and can be used to receive Apple ID verification codes.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915

But when I view devices on the Apple ID page I only get the option to remove the device, I don’t have the option to set the device to untrusted.